# JButton doesnt show text; fills JFrame

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I am trying to make a JFrame with a button in it, but my button doesnt have my wanted text! I'm setting it in the button constructor AND afterwards with setText, but it still doesnt show up! Also, the button fills the whole frame, is there a way to make it not stick to the edges of the JFrame?

```java
import javax.swing.*;

public class main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame("8 Game");
        mainWindow.setSize(200, 200);
        JButton eightButton = new JButton("8");
        eightButton.setText("8");
        eightButton.setSize(30, 30);
        eightButton.setBounds(5, 5, 25, 25);
        eightButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        eightButton.setAction(new buttonAction());
        mainWindow.add(eightButton);
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: The default layout manager of a JFrame is BorderLayout, which doesn't really care about the bounds you set on your JButton.

Comment: Take a look to [How to use buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why does it work for me and not you? (with the FlowLayout suggested by others

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame("8 Game");
        mainWindow.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainWindow.setSize(200, 200);
        JButton eightButton = new JButton("8");
        eightButton.setText("8");
        eightButton.setSize(30, 30);
        eightButton.setBounds(5, 5, 25, 25);
        //eightButton.setAction(new buttonAction());
        //eightButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);


        mainWindow.add(eightButton);
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

an `Action` needs a title. If you don't specify one, the button will have no title. If you did this

```
 eightButton.setAction(new buttonAction(), "8");
```

it would work.

Comment: WTF, blame the setAction! WHY?! removing the setAction worked!

Comment: Action need a title. If you don't specify one, your button won't show anything

Answer (score 3):

Use a layout manager that respects the component's preferred size

```
mainWindow.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
```

Comment: i removed the borders, but kept the size, 30*30, and also tested with 130*130. Now the window looks like this (and still has no text): http://puu.sh/6kRx9.jpg

Comment: Remove the `setSize` and `setBounds` calls for the button

Comment: didnt change anything :(

Comment: call `pack()` before `setVisible()`

Comment: @Pwnie2012 worked fine when I tested it, are you running the updated code?

Comment: pack() makes it contract too minimum size with a slight space between window bounds and the TINY button

Answer (score 2):

Swing components expect a layout manager context when they are added to a window.

The default layout is BorderLayout, which is why you're getting that odd behavior. With only a single element, BorderLayout fills the pane with that element.

Try something like FlowLayout or AbsoluteLayout (or null)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html

Answer (score 2):

Use another `LayoutManager` default frame's layout manager is `BorderLayout`  that if you add a component without specification will add to the center. You can use `FlowLayout`. See example with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` you ensure that will run in `EDT`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame("8 Game");
                mainWindow .setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                mainWindow.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                mainWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                JButton eightButton = new JButton("8");
                eightButton.setText("8");
                eightButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
                eightButton.setAction(new buttonAction());
                mainWindow.add(eightButton);
                mainWindow.pack();
                mainWindow.setVisible(true);
            }

        });

    }
```

Take a look of more complete correct examples in official tutorials [How to use Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)